# Why is my apk output versionCode not updating correctly?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to minimize my apps apk size by splitting them by abi. I'm using the following [guide](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-Variant-API-Version-Code-support.) for doing that.

The problem I'm having is that the versionCode is not updating correctly on the output apk. I added printf to test versionCode was being computed properly and it was.

Any ideas would help.

Here is my gradle file. Some parts omitted..

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.vblast.test"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 41
        versionName "1.4.7"
    }

    // Special flavor dimensions for different markets and
    // versions paid and free.
    flavorDimensions 'market', 'version'

    productFlavors {
        google {
            dimension 'market'
        }
        amazon {
            dimension 'market'
        }
        mobiroo {
            dimension 'market'
        }
        // Base free version
        free {
            dimension 'version'
        }
        // Base pro version
        pro {
            dimension 'version'
        }
    }

    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a' //, 'mips'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}

// map for the version code
ext.versionCodes = [armeabi:1, 'armeabi-v7a':2, x86:3, mips:4]

import com.android.build.OutputFile

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    // assign different version code for each output
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        int abiVersionCode = project.ext.versionCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))?:0
        output.versionCodeOverride = (abiVersionCode * 1000000) + android.defaultConfig.versionCode
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see in your AndroidManifest.xml your versionCode?

Comment: No versionCode or versionName used on my manifest. I allow gradle to set that.

Comment: @Jona : Did you find any solution for it ?